# Getting the Total Number of Elements From All Lists Belonging to An Object

Tags: c#, linq

I have been given some code that has objects composed of lists of different types. A simple example of what I mean:

```
public class Account
{
    private long accountID;
    private List<string> accountHolders;
    private List<string> phoneNumbers;
    private List<string> addresses;

    public Account()
    {
        this.accountHolders = new List<string>();
        this.phoneNumbers = new List<string>();
        this.addresses = new List<string>();
    }

    public long AccountID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.accountID;
        }
        set
        {
            this.accountID = value;
        }
    }
}
```

For a requirement I need to get the total amount of elements in each list for validation purposes. I have the following method which works:

```
public class AccountParser
{
    // Some code
    public int CountElements(Account acct)
    {
        int count = 0;
        count += acct.accountHolders.Count();
        count += acct.phoneNumbers.Count();
        count += acct.addresses.Count();

        return count;
    }
}
```

but was wondering if there was a better way to do this. I know I can enumerate over a List with Linq but I can't seem to get it to work in this case.

Comment: You *could* do it with reflection, if you wanted it to be way too complicated, unreadable, and (if it ever matters) slow. I'd keep what you got, if I were me. Fortunately I'm not.

Comment: @EdPlunkett thanks Ed, that was what I was leaning towards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**What you're doing is the right thing**

You could do it in one line without declaring any variable

```
public int CountElements(Account acct)
{
    return acct.accountHolders.Count() + acct.phoneNumbers.Count() + acct.addresses.Count();
}
```

But it doesn't change much.

---

The ammount of lists is static, because the class is static, so it doesn't make sense to use Reflection if the structure wont change.

Now you could have more than one `Account` classes with different types of lists. In that case, i would create an abstract `AbsAccount` class, that has an abstract CountElements property:

```
public abstract class AbsAccount 
{
    public abstract int CountElements { get; }
}

public class Account: AbsAccount 
{
    private List<string> accountHolders;
    private List<string> phoneNumbers;
    private List<string> addresses;

    public override int CountElements
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.accountHolders.Count() 
                + this.phoneNumbers.Count() 
                + this.addresses.Count(); 
        }
    }
}


public class AccountParser
{
    // Some code
    public int CountElements(AbsAccount acct)
    {
        return acct.CountElements;
    }
}
```

But maybe im taking it too far...

Comment: Thanks for the re-assurance, nice to know I'm not crazy and was looking at it correctly. I can't add an abstract class as the code already exists and I am just writing some "helper" code.

Answer (score 2):

You can add items to a list then call `.Sum`method on it, but it's not better from performance point of view.

```
public class AccountParser
{
    // Some code
    public int CountElements(Account acct)
    {

        List<string> all = new List<string>();
        all.AddRange(acct.accountHolders);
        all.AddRange(acct.phoneNumbers);
        all.AddRange(acct.addresses);

        return all.Count();
    }
}
```

Another approach will be (because I can see you are not exposing directly your lists) to use observer pattern, and update the number of elements in another field or even list, every time you are updating one of your lists. Then get the value from that field, but I think the best way is the one you have already adopted.